# d3.js - using slider to dynamically change graph

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, graph, data-visualization

I have a graph where each edge has a numerical value between 0 and 1. I want to add a slider to the webpage so that as the slider value varies between 0 and 1, only edges with a larger value than the slider are drawn. Is there some sort of canonical way to do this? I am pretty new to d3 and have looked at the basic force graph code, but unsure where to proceed from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will expose to javascript a UI widget slider - put this in your html body block

```
<p>Volume</p>
<input id="volume" type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"/>
```

then put this into your javascript

```
  document.getElementById('volume').addEventListener('change', function() {

      var curr_volume = this.value;

      console.log("curr_volume ", curr_volume);

      // now do something with curr_volume
  });
```

this will get you up and running until some canonical trick appears